# jquery ajax wrap with json.parse

Tags: jquery

the answer should be received parsed so that you can save yourself the call to JSON.parse(). However, the function does not return the processed response. how is it please.

```
function ajax(data) {

    var dev = true;

    if(dev) console.log('argument', data);

    return $.post({
      url: ajaxNode,
      data: data
    }).done(e => {

        try {

            var data = JSON.parse(e);
            if(dev) console.log('response', data);
            return data;

        }
        catch(er) {

            if(dev) console.log('error', e);

        }


    });

}

ajax({ c: [1,2] }).done(e => {

    console.log(e); // no object

});
```

Answer (score 0):

with then() instead of done() works

```
function ajax(data) {

    var dev = true;

    if(dev) console.log('argument', data);

    return $.post({
      url: ajaxNode,
      data: data
    }).then(e => {

        try {

            var data = JSON.parse(e);
            if(dev) console.log('response', data);
            return data;

        }
        catch(er) {

            if(dev) console.log('error', e);

        }


    });

}

ajax({ c: [1,2] }).then(e => {

    console.log(e); // object

});
```